# Ruby on rails upload parameter is nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload a file in Ruby on Rails using dropzone and paperclip. I have the following code:

```
def create
    puts "MOdel:"
    puts Model.column_names
    @model = Model.new(model_params)
    puts "params:"
    puts (params[:model])[:upload].inspect
    uploaded_io = params[:model][:upload]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end

    # @model.upload_file_name = @model.upload.filename
    # @model.upload_content_type = @model.upload.content_type

    # FileUtils.mv(@model.upload.tempfile, "public/uploads/" + @model.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @model.save
        puts "successfully saved model"
        format.html { redirect_to @model, notice: 'Model was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @model }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

......

```
 def model_params
      params.require(:model).permit(:upload)#:upload => [:filename, :content_type, :upload_file_size, :created_at])
    end
```

And the output of my server looks like this:

```
Started POST "/models" for 73.34.17.74 at 2017-03-12 23:48:37 +0000
Cannot render console from 73.34.17.74! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ModelsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sE2aEnxC8K33r+s/oPOrz7HtslQq3HO6ipn971wShOsghbzp/u2qKNSXiNRQ0btP2EqA0pIvMhfBwTxVS+Bz6g==", "model"=>{":upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f1d5c130d78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170312-9855-routhl.jpg>, @original_filename="3hajXfT.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"model[:upload]\"; filename=\"3hajXfT.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}
MOdel:
id
upload_file_name
upload_content_type
upload_file_size
upload_updated_at
created_at
updated_at
Unpermitted parameter: :upload
params:
nil
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/models_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

I also have a view file that looks like this:

```
<div class="overlay hidden">
  <div class="row overlay-inner">
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" class="close-uploads" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <%= form_for(@model, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}) do |f|  %>
        <div class="fallback">
          <%= f.file_field :upload %><br>
          <%= f.submit "Upload my file" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    </div>

    <div class="index row">
      <%= render "uploads/helper.html.erb" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my uploads.js file looks like :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require dropzone
//= require_tree .
$(document).ready(function(){
    // This handles the actual upload js
  // disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;


  var dropzone = new Dropzone (".dropzone", {
    maxFilesize: 256, // Set the maximum file size to 256 MB
    paramName: "model[:upload]", // Rails expects the file upload to be something like model[field_name]
    addRemoveLinks: false // Don't show remove links on dropzone itself.
  });

  dropzone.on("success", function(file) {
    this.removeFile(file)
    $.getScript("/upload")
  })

});
```

I am totally stuck here as to why my params object is nil. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? I've gone over dozens of questions here, and none of that has worked.

Comment: In your JS, you're setting the param name to be `"model[:upload]"` - symbols don't exist in JS. You can see in your Rails logs that the file is being submitted as ":upload".

Comment: Holy shit, I have spent almost 5 hours looking through this, and that was it. Thank you so much. I would buy you a beer if I could.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `puts` use `Rails.logger.debug`. It shows up in `log/development.log`.